# set a price cap for spot instances with EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks

I would like to use spot instances in my cluster. I was trying to create a node group with a spot priced launch template when I discovered it's not possible to specify instance market options like maximum price.

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/15118

This seems like a pretty major limitation seeing as spot instances can spike up in price to orders of magnitude more than on-demand.

https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/893/why-is-the-aws-ec2s-spot-price-greater-than-the-on-demand-price

Is there really no way around this? Is no one using spot instances in EKS?

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look for you in the Python SDK documentation. I didn't find any mention about what you are looking for in the API https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/eks.html#EKS.Client.create_nodegroup I guess the same applies in terms of IaC. I would suggest you reach out to your Technical Account Manager (TAM) or AWS Support and let them know about your needs. They will be able to create a feature request for you.